# Proportionally resize a constantly growing div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that acts as a progress bar, constantly growing an amount proportional to the browser width. `timerLength += $(window).width()/numSlides * .01;` When the bar reaches the edge of the browser its width is set to 0 and it begins to fill again.

I want this to scale fluidly, but I do not know how to make the bar resize proportionally when the browser is resized. It works correctly in different browser sizes, but as of now, if you resize the browser, the width of the bar stays the same, until it reaches the edge of the browser and sets itself to 0 again.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: I think you can make its width to be a percentage of the container's width.

Comment: Create a jsFiddle please

Answer (score 0):

Think about using a percentage width.  Calculate the percentage it should be filled, size the div appropriately to the window (either by manually recaluatling it's size in JS and updating it or pure CSS) and let the browser handle all the scaling.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all the code its a bit hard to judge but it sounds like you just need to use % widths rather than a fixed width.

Make you loader con 100% width and display:block; this will make it fluidly resize to the screen. Then when you are filling the bar in use % again.